# How to flatten complex json before converting into Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to convert the complex json into the pandas dataframe but i am having problem when i am converting it. I am not possibly sure how to convert the complex json into the pandas dataframe.

[image]

**I want to show all the data in the dataframe this is how i am getting it and i am sharing the format of my json data so that it can be understandable**

```
{
  '1164223': {
    'fullSummaryLink': '/series/19014/scorecard/1164223/new-zealand-a-vs-india-a-1st-unofficial-odi-india-a-tour-of-nz-2018-19',
    'innings': {
      '1': {
        'batsmen': [
          {
            'name': 'HD Rutherford',
            'href': 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/331375.html',
            'stats': {
              'runs': {
                'name': 'runs',
                'text': 'RUNS',
                'value': '70'
              },
              'ballsFaced': {
                'name': 'ballsFaced',
                'text': 'BF',
                'value': '66'
              },
              'notouts': {
                'name': 'notouts',
                'text': 'Not Out',
                'value': '0'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            'name': 'JDS Neesham',
            'href': 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/355269.html',
            'stats': {
              'runs': {
                'name': 'runs',
                'text': 'RUNS',
                'value': '79'
              },
              'ballsFaced': {
                'name': 'ballsFaced',
                'text': 'BF',
                'value': '48'
              },
              'notouts': {
                'name': 'notouts',
                'text': 'Not Out',
                'value': '1'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        'team': {
          'teamDisplayName': 'NEW ZEALAND A',
          'innDisplayName': 'INNINGS',
          'runs': 308,
          'overs': 50,
          'wickets': 6,
          'description': 'complete',
          'inningsRunWicket': '308/6',
          'inningStatus': ''
        },
        'bowlers': [
          {
            'name': 'S Kaul',
            'href': 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/326017.html',
            'stats': {
              'overs': {
                'name': 'overs',
                'text': 'O',
                'value': '10'
              },
              'conceded': {
                'name': 'conceded',
                'text': 'R',
                'value': '74'
              },
              'wickets': {
                'name': 'wickets',
                'text': 'E',
                'value': '2'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            'name': 'K Gowtham',
            'href': 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/424377.html',
            'stats': {
              'overs': {
                'name': 'overs',
                'text': 'O',
                'value': '9'
              },
              'conceded': {
                'name': 'conceded',
                'text': 'R',
                'value': '46'
              },
              'wickets': {
                'name': 'wickets',
                'text': 'E',
                'value': '1'
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      '2': {
        'bowlers': [
          {
            'name': 'HK Bennett',
            'href': 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/226493.html',
            'stats': {
              'overs': {
                'name': 'overs',
                'text': 'O',
                'value': '10'
              },
              'conceded': {
                'name': 'conceded',
                'text': 'R',
                'value': '65'
              },
              'wickets': {
                'name': 'wickets',
                'text': 'E',
                'value': '2'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            'name': 'LH Ferguson',
            'href': 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/493773.html',
            'stats': {
              'overs': {
                'name': 'overs',
                'text': 'O',
                'value': '10'
              },
              'conceded': {
                'name': 'conceded',
                'text': 'R',
                'value': '75'
              },
              'wickets': {
                'name': 'wickets',
                'text': 'E',
                'value': '2'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        'batsmen': [
          {
            'name': 'V Shankar',
            'href': 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/477021.html',
            'stats': {
              'runs': {
                'name': 'runs',
                'text': 'RUNS',
                'value': '87'
              },
              'ballsFaced': {
                'name': 'ballsFaced',
                'text': 'BF',
                'value': '80'
              },
              'notouts': {
                'name': 'notouts',
                'text': 'Not Out',
                'value': '1'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            'name': 'SS Iyer',
            'href': 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/642519.html',
            'stats': {
              'runs': {
                'name': 'runs',
                'text': 'RUNS',
                'value': '54'
              },
              'ballsFaced': {
                'name': 'ballsFaced',
                'text': 'BF',
                'value': '54'
              },
              'notouts': {
                'name': 'notouts',
                'text': 'Not Out',
                'value': '0'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        'team': {
          'teamDisplayName': 'INDIA A',
          'innDisplayName': 'INNINGS',
          'runs': 311,
          'overs': 49,
          'wickets': 6,
          'description': 'target reached',
          'inningsRunWicket': '311/6',
          'inningStatus': ''
        }
      }
    },
    'isAvailable': True
  }
}
```

this is my python code which converts the dictionary of json values into the pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in scorecard_summary.items()})
df
```

Comment: Maybe [this blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10) and [this library](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten) can help you.

Comment: a bit unclear: you have posted a picture with the final dataframe, was that the current output or a **desired** output?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thats the output i am having.. that is not the desired output.. I want to show every single data inside the dataframe which is in the json.

Comment: ok, so you need to post a fragment of desired dataframe (how it should look)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have given the sample json format I want to show every single element in the dataframe.